# What restrictions are there during HBase compactions?

Tags: hbase

I'm wondering **whether or not there are any restrictions during HBase minor/major compactions**. I read [the online document](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#compaction) but could not find any explicit mention about restrictions. What I'm mostly worrying about is whether read/write operations are blocked during compactions. Could you give me some insights, please?

EDIT (2012-May-25)
I posted the same question to the HBase mailing list and could get an 
[answer](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-user/201205.mbox/%3CCAN_xCOcvNpKHaog%3DeaYcMjvWezL4MKwTB83PkgEWeN-Rry3etw%40mail.gmail.com%3E)
saying "**No operations are blocked during compactions.**"
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the same question to the HBase mailing list and could get an [answer](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-user/201205.mbox/%3CCAN_xCOcvNpKHaog%3DeaYcMjvWezL4MKwTB83PkgEWeN-Rry3etw%40mail.gmail.com%3E) saying "**No operations are blocked during compactions.**" Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just curious, how read and write operations will be working when all the HFiles are merging in a region? In case of write operation, does Hbase create another separate HFile independently of HFiles involved in the merging?